# Xamarin Forms Android: no connectivity on awake when permissions are set to ask every time. Is this a Xamarin issue?

Tags: android, forms, xamarin, permissions, connectivity

**Description**
Xamarin forms Android: After the app is put to sleep (after 2 minutes), when attempting to resume, the app loses the ability to connect to the internet:
`Connectivity.NetworkAccess == NetworkAccess.None`
This only occurs if the user has selected Location permissions as 'Ask every time'
If the Location permissions are fully granted, the app works as expected.

Comment: Could you please post the steps of reproducing this problem or a basic demo to github or onedriver so that we can test on our side?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.